# "Where" in a subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I want to express that it is hard to continue your work after hours of exhausting reading. But I have no idea if the usage of *where* is proper in the following:

> We might all have similar experiences that our brains go blanked out after hours of reading hardcore material regarding, for instance, math, where extra effort made to continue working is in vain.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

I have much less issue with your use of the word "where" than with the run-on nature of your sentence.  Consider this:

> We might all have similar experiences that our brains go blank after hours of reading.  When reading hardcore material, for instance math, this is especially true.  In cases like these, extra effort made to continue working is in vain.

I've turned one sentence in to three, by adding a few extra words, but the intention is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

*Where* is acceptable. It is [a subordinating conjunction](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/subordinatingconjunctions.html).

If you don't like the way it sounds, you could try another way of saying it:

> We might all have similar experiences that our brains go blanked out after hours of reading hardcore material regarding subjects in which extra effort made to continue working is in vain.

This sentence is rather imposing and would be less so if simplified, as cobaltduck demonstrates.

I noticed you wrote

> We might all have similar experiences that our brains...

This is actually the improper part of the sentence. *That* is not a subordinating conjunction, so it should be changed to *in that*.